# Library's all code is written by Swift but Framework's header seems Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xamarin, frameworks

I'm making app with using Xamarin.
I have to bind some iOS framework which is written by Swift to CSharp.

Sad news is Xamarin does not support bind Swift framework at this moment, So I almost gave up.

But I have a question.

Header files of the library that I've built to framework looks Objective C. But All source code is written by Swift. (this framework : https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/IOS-DFU-Library)

What is this?
Is this natural or they did something extra work to make it as Objective C when it's in framework?

This means that I can keep doing binding work?

Please correct me, if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

As far as xamarin is concern, it doesn't matter if a Cocoa lib is written using objective C or swift, or C++ for that matters.

What you'll have to compile the lib into a *.framework compiled library using xcode. So swift or objc, well, doesn't matter.

Simply open the project in Xcode and build it. Obviously, don’t do build and run as you can’t run it (again unless you have a test suite). Now, look under the Products group in XCode and you should see a file called DFULibrary.framework.

Once you have the compiled binary, then you'll have to encapsulate it in a C# (or F#) iOS binding project (again, they say ios binding, not objc binding nor swift binding... guesss why :p ) as explain here : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries/
Now, it's true that they say:

> To do a comprehensive binding, you will want to understand the
>   Objective-C API definition and familiarize yourself with the .NET
>   Framework Design guidelines.

but I would pin that on a lack of update of the documentation. Just replace ObjC understanding by swift understanding :)

YOu will end up with a C# api anyway.

Enjoy

Comment: Swift does not support being compiled to a static `.a` library, it is only exposed as a Framework. Xamarin currently does not bind to Swift frameworks as you would need to either tag all the functions you need as public/ObjC exported and then create header files for them that could be bound via interop. The other way would be to create a ObjC library project, include your Swift framework project into it and than expose the Swift items you need via ObjC code. You could then bind to this static lib via interop and include the Swift framework in your Xamarin.iOS project...

Comment: Thanks Florian and @SushiHangover . I guess Sushi's answer is only choice I can make. As Florian said, I made compiled and combined achitectures framework already. But binding to Csharp doesn't work because what Sushi answered. I may have to make objc library as Sushi said.

Comment: wha about that ? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/embedded_frameworks/

Comment: Well I tried to compile the project into a static library (.a) instead of a framework, and it turns out that swift is not supported for static library... That's unfortunate... So I guess yeah, create a static lib that reference the framework might do

Comment: Thanks so much your testing. I will give it a shot what Sushi suggest.

Comment: ah it's semms that it's possible to bind framework with objective Sharpie : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/platform-features/native-frameworks/